# Is there anything wrong that a user prefers upvoting over accepting replies?

Tags: discussion, support, moderators, account-suspension

- Does a user have their right for preferring upvoting over accepting replies?
- Can moderators suspend a user for preferring upvoting over accepting replies?

Comment: What does "preferring upvoting over accepting replies" mean? How can you "accept a reply"? If you're referring to accepting an _answer_, it's purely optional (but encouraged, if an answer does in fact resolve the question), as is voting. As far as I know, the only way to get banned with votes is by abusing the system, like serial voting and using multiple accounts. Also, voting and accepting answers aren't mutually exclusive. You'd usually upvote an answer you'd accept, and you may vote on other answers that were helpful.

Comment: I was suspended on Latin.StackExchange, for reasons including not accepting the answers made by the moderators. I have explained to them that I almost always upvoted replies that are not based on bad intentions, but not accept answers reasily.

Comment: I doubt that was the reason, but please provide evidence.

Comment: If you don't believe me, then it is useless for me to continue.  It is listed in their suspending message to me. When moderators suspend a user, their behaviors have never been questioned.

Comment: Apparently you feel you've been wronged, but you're asking me to just take your side without any evidence? Obviously, moderators can't ban people for not accepting answers, and my guess is that's not what they did since they'd risk being caught for abuse. You probably just _think_ that's what they did, so you should provide evidence so the wrong can be fixed. "When moderators suspend a user, their behaviors have never been questioned" -- not really, they're questioned all the time on meta sites by folks such as yourself.

Comment: Based on this as well as [the other question of yours](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/390538/348196), it sounds like you're trying to ask about the reasons you claim were given to you by the mods one by one, but you're doing so without giving us any context. If you don't feel comfortable sharing more information, that's fine. But in this case, you should take it up with Latin mods, then SE employees (via the contact page) if needed.

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine I have many similar unjust experiences from some moderators in the past, and I have only one success with SE employees. They don't usually reply or respond. It is not helpful to engage with Latin mods when they are the one who made the accusation and suspension

Comment: Please note that asking here about small bits without providing any context whatsoever and then trying to use the answers to support your case would be disingenuous because we can't see the full picture. (I'm not saying that's what you're doing. Just wanted to point this out)

Comment: You are making claims about your suspension. You need to provide evidence for them, or else face the (historically validated and legitimate) base hypotheses that 1. you were not suspended for what you claim, and 2. that you are not here acting in good faith. A screenshot of the moderator message in full is all you need to put in the question to show the real reasons and show that you're correct.

Comment: I believe this is highly relevant to the discussion and sheds light over question: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/146780

Comment: @AugustoVasques I wish that you use your digging skill to find more history around and more importantly before that happened, to get a fuller context and picture. I had reason to insist, after realizing the post was duplicated by something outside my control. There had been things that happened before and led to my responses

Comment: The linked incident in the chatroom has nothing to do with upvoting or accepting answers. But as always, the onus is on you to show us the problem.

Comment: *"to find more history around and more importantly before that happened, to get a fuller context and picture"* we could just read the moderator message, that you received, in a screenshot that you can provide in less than a minute. Refusing to do this, given your claims, only cements them as mistruth.

Comment: [It isn't the first time](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389433/how-can-i-find-out-my-posts-questions-or-answers-deleted-not-necessarily-last#comment730295_389433). This user has [asked 1,262 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/156458/tim?tab=questions&sort=newest) on Stack Overflow.

Comment: This question is underspecified. It ought to be closed until sufficient information has been provided. It may [take a while](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/141196/tim), though.

Answer (score 15):

> Does a user have their right for preferring upvoting over accepting replies?

Yes.  Accepting answers is not required.  In many cases, the asker is not able to verify the answer with certainty.

> Can moderators suspend a user for preferring upvoting over accepting replies?

No, assuming that it is not part of some other misbehavior, that would be inappropriate.  I could imagine circumstances in which a user not accepting answers is part of something that leads to a suspension. For example, if a user were withholding acceptance conditioned on receiving something they're not entitled to<sup>1</sup>, or using it to bully users into continuing to answer new parts of an ever-changing question, those would be examples of situations in which a user's refusal to accept answers might merit a suspension or other moderator action.

---

<sup>1</sup> I've seen someone withhold acceptance on one site conditioned on receiving some benefit (I forget what, exactly) on another network site; they were suspended, and rightly so.

Comment: thanks. I prefer upvoting over accepting, merely out of personal preference. I have never seen a policy against it, but have been repeated accused by moderators because of it. so I posted my question here. They left messages repeatedly to ask me to accept particular replies, mostly made by them. They said that I am ungrateful and put me under heavy scrutiny before suspension.

Comment: @Tim: Re *"left messages"*: In what form? Where?

Answer (score 13):

A suspension is a significant event, and comes after engagement to try and resolve whatever the underlying problems are.

A mod would not suspend a user just for "not accepting the answers made by the moderators."   There are clearly other things going on.

Consider taking it up directly with the Latin mods - either via public or private chat, or by replying to the mod message.

Comment: you are right, it is one of the reasons they listed in the suspension message and the warning one earlier. I just want to focus on one reason in this post. It is too much to discuss all the reasons in one post.

Comment: Nothing prevents mods (or anybody else for that matter) from *listing* it among reasons. They just can't use it as *the* reason. It *might* influence their opinion of you, but you should assume they have only been given (and allowed to keep) their moderator rights because they are able to see past their own opinion and judge based on objective (I don't know latin.SE, but I assume they don't have local rules that allows suspensions based on anything non-objective) criteria.

Answer (score 8):

Nowhere in the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/1377755) page is it stated that users are obliged to accept an answer. The most is that they *should* accept the answer that they *personally* thought was the best. You could *personally* think that none of the answers should be accepted and upvote them instead, and there is no way for other users, such as moderators, to measure *your personal* feelings.

As for suspensions, those are typically reserved for serious problems, such as disruptive behavior, as outlined in [A Day in the Penalty Box](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/). These require concrete evidence of wrongdoing and are never applied over neglecting to accept answers, unless done as a form of abuse, such as targeting a certain users.

Abstaining from accepting answers is no worse than abstaining from voting. Unless there is an underlying pattern of abuse (e.g. [serial voting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126829/1377755)), accepts and voting (or the lack thereof) are 100 percent at the discretion of the user.